# Asp.net MVC 5 can't get user roles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to get user roles and modify it.
I've tried many ways to get user roles but nothing works.
Is there anything missing?
I can get right User entity but Roles is always null.
Is there any way to do it correctly?
Thanks

```
var user = UserManager.Users.Single(u=>u.Id==id);
var roles = user.Roles;
roles.Add(....)


var user = UserManager.Users.Single(u=>u.Id==id);
user.IsinRole("rolename");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get them via claims:

```
var roles = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims
            .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
            .Select(c => c.Value);
```

To add a user to a role, you can do (**Make sure the role exists in the database though**):

```
var roleresult = UserManager.AddToRole(currentUser.Id, "RoleName");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using an administrator's right and want to modify other users roles, I tried to replace (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity) with user.Claims (which from my first line in code) and still nothing work, any ways to fix it?

Comment: @Neardreams No probs, just use the `UserManager` to add and remove any users from roles

Comment: Thanks a lot ! UserManger.GetRoles(),UserManger.RemoveFromRole(),UserManager.AddToRole() those method works.

Comment: @Neardreams No problems glad I could help. If this was the answer hit the tick next to it to mark at as correct. Welcome to SO!