# mvc 5 asp.net identity role and users, how to lest both in order user with it's roles and remove

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

here the system is like **one user** may have many **roles** so now I am able to list users, but I want to list roles too for example

this controller will list only users,

```
public ActionResult listOfRolesForUser()
        {

            RoleManager<IdentityRole> RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(ndb));
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(ndb));
            ViewBag.AllUsers = UserManager.Users.ToList();
            return View();

        }
```

and this is view or listOfRolesForUser.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "listOfRolesForUser";
}

<h2>listOfRolesForUser</h2>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>User name</td>
        <td>Roles</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item2 in ViewBag.AllUsers)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item2.UserName</td>
            <td>here i need to list related role too</td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

now how I will be able to list like:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asp.net MVC 5 can't get user roles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094754/asp-net-mvc-5-cant-get-user-roles)

Comment: it's little different I want to list them in rows and one operation button to remove

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve both **Users** and **Roles**, you can store both lists and pass to a view model.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

        var users = UserManager.Users;
        var roles = new List<string>();

        // retrieve roles for each user
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            string str = "";
            foreach (var role in UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id))
            {
                str = (str == "") ? role.ToString() : str + " - " + role.ToString();
            }
            roles.Add(str);
        }

        var model = new HomeViewModel()
        {
            // create view model with these fields
            users = users.ToList(),
            roles = roles.ToList()
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Using the view model populate the table, implement `Delete` method in `HomeController` and navigate to `Home/Delete` url through an ajax call.

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.HomeViewModel

<h2>listOfRolesForUser</h2>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>User name</td>
        <td>Roles</td>
        <td>Actions</td>
    </tr>

    @{
        int i = 0;

        foreach (var item in Model.users)
        {
            <tr id="@item.Id">
                <td>@item.UserName</td>
                <td>@Model.roles[i]</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" onclick="deleteUser('@item.Id')" id="btnDelete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" title="Delete">
                        Delete
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            i++;
        }
    }
</table>
```